# Null instead '0000-00-00 00:00:00' in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, datagrip

Before: **mysql 5.6**. One of the columns in the table is created as follows:

```
`f_stamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

When i view this field in mysql client or using DataGrip, this field is displayed correctly.

Now: **mysql 5.7**. The field is not displayed correctly (more precisely, it is causes en error). I delete from mysql config following flags: NO_ZERO_DATE, NP_ZERO_IN_DATE and STRICT_TRANS_TABLES. And now, looking at this field i see:

1. Using mysql-client: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
2. DataGrip: null

---

How to change server's option for support this non-standard datetime value, initialize by '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ?

*UPD:* https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3377

Comment: There was probably a good reason for making this bogus date illegal.  Consider changing the application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the JDBC driver option we changed in DataGrip by default. But you can configure it the way you like:

[image]

Comment: Wow. This took me way to much time to figure out. Can't fathom why they would display a value differently than it technically is reported by the server. Especially in a tool used for technical analysis.